# How should I use nested ifelse statements?

Tags: r, nested-if

I have created a data frame with the following data

```
name <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
age <- c(22,43,12,17,29,5,51,56,9,44)
sex <- c("M","F","M","M","M","F","F","M","F","F")
rock <- data.frame(name,age,sex,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
rock
```

Now I want to find out:

If the name is E to J and sex is not equal to F then the status is "1F", if the name is A to D and age is greater than 15 then the status is "Young". Everything else is "Others"

so for that, i am applying following code:

```
rock$status <- ifelse(rock$name==c("E","F","G","H","I","J")& 
rock$sex!="F","1F",            
ifelse(rock$name==c("E","F","G","H","I","J")&rock$sex=="F","Fenamle",
ifelse(rock$name==c("A","B","C","D") & rock$age>15,"Young","Others")))
rock
```

But i am getting the output like:

```
  name  age    sex    status
1     A   22     M   Young   
2     B   43     F   Young   
3     C   12     M  Others  
4     D   17     M  Young   
5     E   29     M  Others  
6     F    5     F  Others  
7     G   51     F  Others  
8     H   56     M  Others 
9     I    9     F  Others  
10    J   44     F  Others
```

But, it has to be "1F" on E and H.but it is showing "Others"

What wrong have I done into my code?

Please correct me and also give me some valuable suggestions regarding this.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637099/difference-between-the-and-in-operators-in-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We need to use `%in%` instead of `==`:

```
rock$status <- ifelse(rock$name %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J") & 
                        rock$sex != "F", "1F",            
                      ifelse(rock$name %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J") & 
                               rock$sex == "F", "Female",
                             ifelse(rock$name %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D") &
                                      rock$age > 15, "Young", "Others")))
rock

#    name age sex  status
# 1     A  22   M   Young
# 2     B  43   F   Young
# 3     C  12   M  Others
# 4     D  17   M   Young
# 5     E  29   M      1F
# 6     F   5   F  Female
# 7     G  51   F  Female
# 8     H  56   M      1F
# 9     I   9   F  Female
# 10    J  44   F  Female
```

Answer (score 5):

In cases like this, I often prefer pre-allocating indexes and then indexing the unique values with a summation of these. It is faster and more readable than nested `ifelse`'s (imo). An example:

```
i1 <- rock$name %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J") & rock$sex != "F"
i2 <- rock$name %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J") & rock$sex == "F"
i3 <- rock$name %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D") & rock$age > 15

rock$status <- c("Other", "1F", "Female", "Young")[1 + i1 + 2*i2 + 3*i3]
```

which gives the desired result:

> ```
> > rock
>    name age sex status
> 1     A  22   M  Young
> 2     B  43   F  Young
> 3     C  12   M  Other
> 4     D  17   M  Young
> 5     E  29   M     1F
> 6     F   5   F Female
> 7     G  51   F Female
> 8     H  56   M     1F
> 9     I   9   F Female
> 10    J  44   F Female
> ```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution using *joins* and *non-equi joins* to update the `status` column:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(rock)[.(name = LETTERS[1:4], age = 15), on = .(name, age > age), status := "Young"][
  .(name = LETTERS[5:10], sex = "F"), on = .(name, sex), status := "Female"][
    .(name = LETTERS[5:10], status = NA_character_), on = .(name, status), status := "1F"][
      .(status = NA_character_), on = .(status), status := "Other"][]
```

> ```
>     name age sex status
>  1:    A  22   M  Young
>  2:    B  43   F  Young
>  3:    C  12   M  Other
>  4:    D  17   M  Young
>  5:    E  29   M     1F
>  6:    F   5   F Female
>  7:    G  51   F Female
>  8:    H  56   M     1F
>  9:    I   9   F Female
> 10:    J  44   F Female
> ```

---

Unfortunately, non-equi joins do not work with unequal operators `!=`, yet. So,

```
setDT(rock)[.(name = LETTERS[1:4], age = 15), on = .(name, age > age), status := "Young"][
  .(name = LETTERS[5:10], sex = "F"), on = .(name, sex != sex), status := "1F"][]
```

gives an error message. Instead, I had to join on `name` and `sex` first to set `status` to `Female` and then to check for `NA`s in `status` to get the complimentary set.

However, there is another workaround using two non-equi joins instead :

```
setDT(rock)[.(name = LETTERS[1:4], age = 15), on = .(name, age > age), status := "Young"][
  .(name = LETTERS[5:10], sex = "F"), on = .(name, sex < sex), status := "1F"][
    .(name = LETTERS[5:10], sex = "F"), on = .(name, sex > sex), status := "1F"][]
```

Answer (score 2):

With data.table you can do:

```
library(data.table)
rock <- data.table(rock)
rock[name %in% LETTERS[5:10] & sex != "F", status := "1F"]
rock[name %in% LETTERS[1:4] & age > 15, status := "Young"]
rock[is.na(status), status := "Other"]
rock
#     name age sex status
#  1:    A  22   M  Young
#  2:    B  43   F  Young
#  3:    C  12   M  Other
#  4:    D  17   M  Young
#  5:    E  29   M     1F
#  6:    F   5   F  Other
#  7:    G  51   F  Other
#  8:    H  56   M     1F
#  9:    I   9   F  Other
# 10:    J  44   F  Other
```

Comment: you missed a condition, maybe include that as well?

Comment: The condition was not mentioned in the text, but only in the code. That's why I didn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `dplyr`'s `case_when()` function:

```
library(dplyr)

name <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")
age <- c(22,43,12,17,29,5,51,56,9,44)
sex <- c("M","F","M","M","M","F","F","M","F","F")
rock <- data.frame(name,age,sex,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

name_condition_1 <- c("E","F","G","H","I","J")
name_condition_2 <- c("A","B","C","D")

rock %>% mutate(
  status = case_when(
    name %in% name_condition_1 & sex != "F" ~ "1F",
    name %in% name_condition_1 & sex == "F" ~ "Female",
    name %in% name_condition_2 & age >  15  ~ "Young",
    TRUE ~ "Others"
  )
)
```

producing:

```
   name age sex status
1     A  22   M  Young
2     B  43   F  Young
3     C  12   M Others
4     D  17   M  Young
5     E  29   M     1F
6     F   5   F Female
7     G  51   F Female
8     H  56   M     1F
9     I   9   F Female
10    J  44   F Female
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data$status <- ifelse(data$name %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D") & data$age > 15,"Young",ifelse(data$sex != "F" & data$name %in% c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),"1F","Others"))
data
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.