# View all rows where there is a duplicate in one of the columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I want to view **all columns** of **all rows** which contain a duplicate in one of the variables.

```
Col_1 = c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5)
Col_2 = c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c", "a")
df = data.frame(Col_1, Col_2)
```

I have identified the values of Col_1 that are duplicated.

```
dup= df%>%
  group_by(Col_1)%>%
  count(Col_1)%>%
  filter(n > 1)%>%
  ungroup()
```

I have turned this into a set of integers and put into a View() function:

```
dup_id = dup[['Col_1']]

View(df[df$Col_1 == dup_id,])
```

I'd expect the output to contain all rows where `Col_1` is 1 or 4 but instead I'm just shown 4 rows:

```r
(df[df$Col_1 == dup_id,])
#>   Col_1 Col_2
#> 1     1     a
#> 3     1     c
#> 6     4     c
#> 8     4     b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Why is this code not showing me all relevant rows?

Comment: `df[df$Col_1 %in% dup_id,]` should to the job!

Comment: I was just suggesting what @holzben suggested; it works!

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637099/difference-between-the-and-in-operators-in-r

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637099/difference-between-the-and-in-operators-in-r , trying to understand!