# Selecting rows with dataframe$var == c('a', 'b', 'c')

Tags: r

I was trying to select some rows from a dataframe.

```
data(Grunfeld, package="AER")

gf = Grunfeld[Grunfeld$firm == c("General Electric",
                                 "General Motors",
                                 "US Steel",
                                 "Westinghouse"), ]
```

The expected output would have 80 rows, but I got 20.

```
> dim(gf)

[1] 20  5
```

On the other hand, `subset()` worked.

```
gf = subset(x = Grunfeld, firm %in% c("General Electric",
                                      "General Motors",
                                      "US Steel",
                                      "Westinghouse"))

> dim(gf)

[1] 80  5
```

Anyone knows what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command didn't work because you used `==` instead of `%in%`; these perform different operations and so give different results. Try rephrasing your first subsetting command to:

```
gf = Grunfeld[Grunfeld$firm %in% c("General Electric",
                                 "General Motors",
                                 "US Steel",
                                 "Westinghouse"), ]
```

There are already answers that give more information on the differences between these operators (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637099/difference-between-the-and-in-operators-in-r)), if you're curious.

Comment: I was not aware of this difference, maybe this is why I could not find this other solution. Thank you very much.