# subset error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r

so, I am trying to subset a file by a row number id that I gave it. parcels$row_number includes 7075 observations that run from 1-7075; miss_list is a list that has 29 of those row numbers, that I am trying to isolate. I ran this, but got the following error:

```
parcels_subset<- parcels%>% subset(parcels$row_number == miss_list)

In parcels$row_number == miss_list :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
(parcels$row number and miss_list are both characters if that matters)

Comment: We may need `%in%` instead of `==` i..e  `subset(parcels, row_number %in% miss_list)`

Comment: yep, worked perfectly. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637099/difference-between-the-and-in-operators-in-r

Comment: It is just that `==` is elementwise comparison operator.  It works only when the length is 1 (recycles) or when both the lenghts are same