# How to eliminate data (years) from csv using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, code-elimination

I am working on a CSV document using R Studio. I have data from 2008 to 2018, but I want to eliminate 2008, 2009 and 2018 from the dataframe so see how the results change. I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
base.final <- merge(x=base.final, y=base.dividendos, by = c('Ativo',"Data"), 
                    all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)

table(is.na(base.final$SETORES_NEFIN))/12

#eliminating years from the data base
base.final <- base.final[base.final$Data!="2008","2009", "2018",]
```

Error that comes up: `[.data.frame`(base.final, base.final$Data != "2008", "2009",  :
unused argument (alist())

This is a database from stocks, and I need to remove some tickers from the data base as well. Which code should I use? I'm working with dplyr.

I tried changing the last comma but it didn't worked out. I am still learning the language.

Comment: Try this:
`base.final <- base.final[!base.final$Data %in% c("2008","2009", "2018"),]`

Answer (score 0):

as per TheN's comment. You must enclose your tested years as a vector in c() for it to work, and further,the `!=` is a logical comparator that checks if one vector is the same as another. What you want to check is whether the years you give in the vector is somewhere in `Data`.

The difference between `==`/`!=` and `%in%` can be a bit challenging to understand, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/42637469/4574789 explains it excellently.

It is nice to include a reproducible example when asking for help, so that those that helps can actually write code that have a chance of working in your user case.

I have NO idea what your data contains or the structure of it, but suppose:

```
base.final <- data.frame(SETORES_NEFIN = c("Guaraná", 
                                           "Rubberduck", 
                                           "Mexico cartel", 
                                           "Sugartown"),
                     Data = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2018"))

# A subset of the data excluding some years
subset(base.final, !Data %in% c("2010", "2008))
```