# Binding rows only if the column hase the same character variable in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames (`d1` and `d2`), they both have the same column names. I have one column called `label_name` in both which is a character with species names. Data frame 1 (`d1`) has only my species of interest (A and B), while data frame 2 (`d2`) has other species that I am not interested about as well as the ones I need (A, B, C, D).
I want to bind the rows from `d2` into `d1` ONLY when label_name = A and B.

I tried using the `if` function, `filter`, and `merge`. But none of them worked.

Comment: `rbind(d1, subset(d2, label_name %in% c("A", "B")))`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Isabella Avo! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. (If my comment doesn't work for you, please [edit] your question. Thanks!)

Comment: Thank you! the code works! I have never seen the %in% and i will look it up!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IsabellaAvo, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15358006/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637099/3358272