# Cannot replace factor values

Tags: r

I have a dataset,`prgeng`. 7 columns, 1 of it is `educ`.

I want to replace the values of `educ` with other values. I need to replace values 1:9 with 1, 10:12 with 2, 13 with 3 and so on.

It doesnt work using the `:` operator.

```r
prgeng <- load(url('https://github.com/matloff/fasteR/blob/master/data/prgeng.RData?raw=true'))
educ <- prgeng$educ

educ[educ == 1:9] <- 1 # doesnt work
# Warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthWarning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

educ[educ == 1] <- 1 # works
```

I think its weird because this on the other hand works.

```r
t1 <- 1:2500
t1[t1 == 1:1000] <- 1 # this works
```

I get that the warning is key but i cannot get my head around what its supposed to mean. And other examples here are based on slightly different cases. I dont think it happens because `educ` is a factor because:

1. i converted educ to a vector and it changed nothing
2. Im able to change the values one by one

Comment: Try `educ[educ %in% 1:9] <- 1`.  `==` is elementwise operator.  So, it recycles if the length of the rhs is less than the one on the lhs.  If it is not a multiple, then it shows the warning

Comment: Agreed, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15358006/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637099/3358272

Comment: @akrun that was it. Thank you!! could you post it as an answer so i can close this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%in%` instead of `==` as `==` is elementwise operator

```
educ[educ %in% 1:9] <- 1
```