# How I pass a file with the mapping onto filter function?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am trying to understand whether I can pass a file with a data dictionary into filter function ?

This is my code:

```
 dplyr::filter(username != 'kgrf808' & username != 'kkwf800' & username != 'kpzl632')
```

Yet, instead of passing the ''kgrf808', etc , I want to pass a column of a csv file, containing all these id's so that it filters it automatically. I may end up with 10 codes.

Is this somehow possible? I want to keep tidyverse functionality as much as I can.

Comment: Import the csv. Say it's name is `df`, and the name of the column with the ID's is `ID`, do `dplyr::filter(! username %in% df$ID)`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15358006/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637099/3358272 for comparisons of `==` versus `%in%`.

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro - the suggested code worked , and it is very elegant, intuitive! Please post it as an answer so that I can thick it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the csv. Say it's name is `df`, and the name of the column with the ID's is `ID`, do:

```
dplyr::filter(! username %in% df$ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

To the same effect, you could use an anti-join, live-loading the text file with users to omit:

```
## create file with rogue users to filter out:
data.frame(rogue_users = c('kgrf808', 'kkwf800', 'kpzl632')) |>
write.table(file = 'rogue_users.csv')
```

```
library(dplyr)

all_users <- data.frame(all_users = c('kgrf808', 'kkwf800', 'kpzl632', 'abc1234')) 

all_users |>
    anti_join(read.table('rogue_users.csv'),
              by = c('all_users' = 'rogue_users')
    )
```

result:

```
  all_users
1   abc1234
```