# Using 'IF' operator to check if a given value in a dataframe cell belongs to a 'SET' of values

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, logic, logical-operators

I have a data.frame with names of animals

```
x=data.frame(c("lion","tiger","cow","vulture","hyena","leopard","deer","gazzelle"))
colnames(x)=c('animal')

#create sets of animals based on the their diet

carnivore=c("lion","tiger","leopard")
herbivore=c("cow","deer","gazzelle")
omnivore=c("vulture","hyena")

x$diet=NA   ## Add a new column where I want to enter if the animal is one of herbivore, carnivore or omnivore based on the value in x$animal

for (i in 1:(nrow(x))) {
  if (x$animal[i] 'is a subset of' "Omnivore") {
    x$diet[i] = "Omnivore"
  } else if (x$animal[i] 'is a subset of' "Carnivore") {
    x$diet[i] = "Carnivore"
  } else if (x$animal[i] 'is a subset of' "Herbivore") {
    x$diet[i] = "Herbivore"
  }
}
```

I am not quite able to write the code equivalent of 'is a subset of' in R, which I believe must have a simple solution. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: No need for forloop, use `ifelse` instead of `if else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code needs [`%in%` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637099/680068):

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(x))) {
  if (x$animal[i] %in% omnivore) {
    x$diet[i] = "Omnivore"
  } else if (x$animal[i] %in% carnivore) {
    x$diet[i] = "Carnivore"
  } else if (x$animal[i] %in% herbivore) {
    x$diet[i] = "Herbivore"
  }
}
```

I prefer nested `ifelse()` instead of `forloop + if{}else{}`:

```
x$diet <- ifelse(x$animal %in% carnivore, "Carnivore",
                 ifelse(x$animal %in% herbivore, "Herbivore",
                        ifelse(x$animal %in% omnivore, "Omnivore", "Other")))
x
#     animal      diet
# 1     lion Carnivore
# 2    tiger Carnivore
# 3      cow Herbivore
# 4  vulture  Omnivore
# 5    hyena  Omnivore
# 6  leopard Carnivore
# 7     deer Herbivore
# 8 gazzelle Herbivore
```

Comment: thank you, both for fixing it in the way I was trying and for showing me a more efficient way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the the `%in%` operator:

```
x$diet[x$animal %in% omnivore] <- "Omnivore"
x$diet[x$animal %in% carnivore] <- "Carnivore"
x$diet[x$animal %in% herbivore] <- "Herbivore"
```

Answer (score 2):

With base R, you can try `stack` + `merge`

```
> lst <- list(Carnivore = carnivore, Herbivore = herbivore, Omnivore = omnivore)

> merge(x, setNames(stack(lst), c("animal", "diet")), sort = FALSE)
    animal      diet
1     lion Carnivore
2    tiger Carnivore
3      cow Herbivore
4  vulture  Omnivore
5    hyena  Omnivore
6  leopard Carnivore
7     deer Herbivore
8 gazzelle Herbivore
```

Comment: diet values are with capital letters.

Comment: @zx8754 aha, you are right. now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your element in a named list and `stack`:

```r
lookup <- stack(dplyr::lst(carnivore, herbivore, omnivore))
```

Or like this if you want to update `x` with `match`:

```r
x$diet <- lookup$ind[match(x$animal, lookup$values)]

#     animal      diet
# 1     lion carnivore
# 2    tiger carnivore
# 3      cow herbivore
# 4  vulture  omnivore
# 5    hyena  omnivore
# 6  leopard carnivore
# 7     deer herbivore
# 8 gazzelle herbivore
```

Comment: diet values are with capital letters.